# Docker container management solution

Tags: node.js, docker

We've NodeJS applications running inside docker containers. Sometimes, if any process gets locked down or due to any other issue the app goes down and we've to manually login to each container n restart the application. I was wondering 
if there is any sort of control panel that allow us to easily and quickly restart those and see the whole health of the system.

Please Note: we can't use --restart flag because essentially application doesn't exist with exist code. It run into problem like some process gets blocked, things are just getting bogged down vs any crashes and exist codes. That's why I don't think restart policy will help in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you consider using the new [HEALTHCHECK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/healthcheck) directive in Docker 1.12 to define a custom check for your locking condition. This feature can be combined with the new Docker swarm [service feature](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/deploy-service/) to specify how many copies of your container you want to have running.